# EasyOCR + PyInstaller creating infinite processes

Tags: python-3.x, image, pyinstaller, ocr, executable

> This is my first question here, if I'm doing something bad, please let me know.

I'm working on a venv, python 3.8.5 x64, on windows 10, my laptop doesn't have GPU.

So, I have this program that ends up passing an image (as array of bytes) to the readtext() method of EasyOCR, on my editor I've got no problem and it works real good, even with no GPU. When I export it to PyInstaller the result is my memory being consumed by an ever-increasing amount of processes coming from the program.

This is a simplified version of what I'm trying to do. It gets screen coordinates, then takes a screenshot of the selected area and transforms it to a byte array, then it get passed to the OCR library to get the text in the area we selected first.

```py
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab
import easyocr, io


def image_to_byte_array(image) -> bytearray:
    image_byte_array = io.BytesIO()
    image.save(image_byte_array, format=image.format)
    image_byte_array = image_byte_array.getvalue()
    return image_byte_array


bbox_size = [498, 448, 771, 497]
image = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=bbox_size)
reader = easyocr.Reader(lang_list=["en"])
text = reader.readtext(image_to_byte_array(image), detail=0)
print(text)
```

I've tested changing python versions, adding multiprocessing.freze_support, and debugged until I got to `text = reader.readtext(image_to_byte_array(image), detail=0)`, that's when the program "stops", but keeps openning more processes until I end up getting this error message.

[image: The error that pops up after like 15 minutes of my memory getting all consumed]

The full version of this program works just fine until I try to create the executable. This is my PyInstaller command: `pyinstaller.exe --onedir --icon="blue-white.ico" --name="MyProgram_TEST" app.py`.

Answer (score 0):

FIXED

```
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab
```

should be

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
```